# How to add the midline between columns for the whole article?

Tags: two-column

I use `\usepackage{dcolumn}` to make the article double columns.

how to add the midline between the two columns for the whole article?

Comment: `dcolumn` is for setting numbers in a table it has no effect on the page layout, you presumably have a class that defaults the `twocolumn` option on `\documentclass`

Answer (score 2):

This is unrelated to `dcolumn` (which is about columns of decimal numbers in tables) but the width of the rule separating the columns of a page may be set by

```
\setlength\columnseprule{1pt}
```

or whatever width you need.

Comment: Thx and thx for your clarification.